# Configuring Single RTE Wrapper for Multiple Classes - Typoscript/Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to write Typoscript that will configure the Typo3 Rich Text Editor to wrap a given element with more than one class.

In the project's TsConfig/Page/rte.txt file, I have:

```
RTE {
    classes {
        button {
            name = Button
        }
    }
```

However, I'd like to create a wrapper that would give the element more than just a single class. The below code doesn't work, but illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
RTE {
    classes {
        button {
            name = Button
        }
        button danger {
            name = Dangerous Button
        }
    }
```

According to [this article](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/51905), this doesn't seem to be possible, but I thought I'd ask and see if someone out there got crafty with their Typoscript and was able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried everything to handle styles for tables that way, but there is currently no way to handle more than one CSS-Class for a RTE style definition.

The only way to handle this, is creating new CSS classes and extend the available button styles via LESS or SCSS.

Comment: As of TYPO3 7.x, there is a solution. See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519743/283854

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3 7 you can use this following RTE configuration to use multiple classes. The magic happens in the class-definition with the attribute "required"

```
RTE {
  default {
    proc.allowedClasses := addToList(btn-dark)
    buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(btn-dark)
  }
  classes.btn-dark {
    name = Dark-Button
    requires = btn btn-small
  }
  classesAnchor.buttonDark {
    class = btn-dark
    type = page
  }
}
```